# when does the database is being destroy in django tests?

Tags: django, django-testing

i'm writing tests for my django app, and i can't understand when does the

database is destroyed..

in django website it says its being destroy "he test databases are destroyed when all the tests have been executed."

i understand from that, that the db is destroyed when the last test command in

the last test*.py file is executed.

so i wrote some tests and i have the following:

```
UserMethodsTests(TestCase):
    def test_get_full_name(self):
        create db objects in model X
        do some stuff on them (not deleting)

    def test_get_username(self):
        * empty line
        create more db objects in model X
```

but if i write "print len(X.objects.all())" in * empty line,

it output 0, as if the db was deleted..

so i don't understand if when does the db destroy/deleted

can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure you're `save()`ing the entries? Can you edit your question to show more test code?

Comment: i can edit the code but it will require a lot of lines to understand all i have done.. for the creation of the model object i use the create() method.

Comment: Is it possible that `test_get_username` is run before `test_get_full_name`?

Comment: no its not. but even if it is, in test_get_full_name i still start from 0 objects